# How to handle playlist with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I want to create application that will play live internet streams with gstreamer. It plays some streams fine, but when it encounters playlist it gives me an error that there is no plugin for "text/uri-list". How can I handle playlist uris in a correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Although there are some discussions about the support of playlist in GStreamer, today, you'll have to catch the missing plugin error (for known playlist mimetypes), and handle the URI yourself. You can use totem-plparser to deal with the actual parsing. [See example code in the reference documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/totem-pl-parser/stable/TotemPlParser.html).